# Fql returning array.. but i need an object

Tags: php, facebook-fql

I'm using this code to get list of friends.

```
    $params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = me()
    OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())",
);

$result = $facebook->api($params);
```

now i'm displaying the picture of user as

```
 echo "<img src='http://graph.facebook.com/".$result[0]."/picture'>";
```

but it is still returning the result as an array like this:
http://graph.facebook.com/array/picture
I need the uid at that place where it is showing array. Help please. its really important

`print_r ($result[0]);` gives the following output----

```
 Array ( [uid] => XXXXXXXX )
```

Comment: `print_r($result)` and post the output of this in question will surely help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 2-D array no need to convert it into object you can still access it

To access uid you have to do something like this

```
echo $result[0]['uid'];
```

Hence you code will become

```
echo "<img src='http://graph.facebook.com/".$result[0]['uid']."/picture'>";
```

If you still want object instead of array you can do type cast.

```
$result_obj= (object) $result[0];
echo $result_obj->uid;
```

Comment: thank u so much shakti.. it worked.. I appreciate ur help .. Thanks :)

Comment: @Anurag: Your Most Welcome say thanks by accepting this answer. you can accept by clicking the right arrow sign.